# 'no UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes instance for -layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElementOfKind

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I get this crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'no UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes instance for 
-layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElementOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader 
at path <NSIndexPath: 0x147b09e0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}'
```

Here at `performBatchUpdates`:

```
    // Reload just the indexPath that loaded
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations:^{
        [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
            [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:paths];
        } completion:nil];
    }];
```

I'm using a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
_collectionViewLayout = layout;
```

I don't understand why this is happening. I'm reloading one of my item cells and it's referring to the supplementary view (which is a header view).

---

EDIT

Does the following have something to do with it?

If I log out the `indexPath`'s in `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` I get for the first call:

```
-[WSImageViewerController collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] [Line 318] indexPath = <NSIndexPath: 0x16d5c990> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}
```

The `indexPath` log for the call to `- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is:

```
-[WSImageViewerController collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:] [Line 399] indexPath = <NSIndexPath: 0x15691570> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}
```

Both indexPaths are `0 - 0`. Does this have something to do with it?

---

EDIT TWO

[image]

Here's what's happening when it crashes. It's trying to load a regular item cell over the header view. There is a large UIActivityIndicatorView in the center, which is from the supplementary header view, so I know that has been added.

Answer (score 0):

This is old and I don't know if it was the case for you, but I want to leave this in case someone encounter the same issue. If you're using custom layouts for your UICollectionViewController make sure that you're using the right name for the supplementary view kind. For example I was using `CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout` and I had to use `CHTCollectionElementKindSectionHeader` instead of `UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader` for the supplementary view kind name.